# user defined function in r that takes color as an input

Tags: r, colors, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a function that plots my data

It has 3 inputs, (dataframe, string, string)

I'm struggling with the last string.

So imagine my function is called plot_by_city(dataframe, "Amsterdam","springgreen4")

then I want it to produce my plot in a way that that is the color.
How do I do this?

This is the code for the function:

```
plot_by_city<- function(dataframe, city_name, color){
  data1 <- filter(dataframe, city == city_name)  
 ggplot(data = data1, aes(x= magnitude, y= injuries)) + 
   geom_point(position= "jitter",shape=23, fill= "red", color="black", size=3)
}
```

red is my default color in case there is not color defined in the input.

Comment: I think that by surrounding `color` with `{{ }}` ggplot will use the content of the string variable to set the color. So maybe try `fill = {{ color }}` and see if that does what you want it to do. Hard to test without you sharing the data as well.

Comment: Thank you! This was a very useful tip, I managed to fix my code with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function in the following way :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

plot_by_city<- function(dataframe, city_name, color = 'red'){
  data1 <- filter(dataframe, city == city_name)  
  ggplot(data = data1, aes(x= magnitude, y= injuries)) + 
    geom_point(position= "jitter",shape=23, fill= color, size=3)
}
#Red color
plot_by_city(dataframe, "Amsterdam")
#springgreen4 color
plot_by_city(dataframe, "Amsterdam","springgreen4")
```

Comment: Ronak, I am actually a little confused about this. I thought that I had to use curly brackets for variables in ggplot2, but in several cases it works just fine w/o. I include them to be thorough but not clear that it is always needed.

Comment: @MarioNiepel It usually depends on what kind of function you are calling and what kind of values do they accept. `fill` here accepts a string variable so using `fill = color` should work when you are passing color as string which can be 'red' or 'springgreen4'. You can test this with `mtcars` dataset `ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x= mpg, y= disp)) + geom_point(position= "jitter",shape=23, fill= "springgreen4", size=3)` and if you wrap "springgreen4" with `{{}}` it works too.

Comment: Yes, definitely works. Is it just because here the function is expecting a string, so if there is a variable (rather than a quote string) ggplot KNOWS that this has to be evaluated -- even if you omit the `{{ }}`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It will always look for a string input for `fill`.